# What serverless plugin collects npm workspace packages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, serverless

A NodeJS project is deployed to AWS as a lambda function using a utility that is called serverless.
There are some plugins that do this stuff, serverless-workspaces-plugin resolves and links hoisted dependencies when packaging.
But it does not work for my case. In my scenario, it is npm workspaces. Following plugins does not do this stuff.
I have not found a required plugin.
Could anybody give an advice? I hope the ready solution has to exist.
Elsewhere I will make a custom serverless deployment script.
Regards.